# Problem with Multiple Instances of Windows Services

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

I have multiple instances of Windows services each running in different server. Each one of the windows service is started when it finds a record in a table. 
Now the Expected functionality is that
If one of the windows service has picked the record, then the other windows services should not be picking up the same record. 
The Actual Functionality:
Each of the windows service is supposed to pick a different record.

All the instances are picking up the same record and processing at the same time, which is creating a problem.

Can anyone suggest a solution to the above?

Additional Details:
I have added the code in which we are checking the dataset contains the record(which we inserted earlier for the windows service to process) then we perform some business, and send a mail. The problem is since there are multiple instances of windows services, I am getting multiple mails which is not desirable.

```
DataSet reportsDs  = new DataSet();            
int ReportID = 0;
int MastReptID = 0;
try
{
    reportsDs = stored procedure to get the dataset in which the record is inserted
    if (reportsDs != null && reportsDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ServiceName.isProcCompleted = false;
        for (int rptcnt = 0; rptcnt < reportsDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count; rptcnt++)
        {
           //some business functions
           //send a mail after finishing the above business process
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that "picks the record". Your problem sounds like a synchronization issue, but without the code we can only guess.

Comment: What type of record are you talking about..? is this a file record or a record in a Database Table..? do you have example of the code for the service that you are using..? you need to give more detail about your process

Comment: It is a database table record.

Comment: And what mechanism have you put in place to stop multiple nodes taking the same record? Do you have a transactional "take and remove" or "take and mark as in use" ?

Comment: I have put a column 'status' which starts at new, and soon as the record is processing the status changes to 'InProgress' but the problem is before the status changes to 'In Progress', another instance of windows service is picking up the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a unique identifier column in the database.
Have each service generate it's own guid on startup.

Fetch a row using modification of following SQL, assuming primary key is id and guid column is LOCKGUID

```
Select TOP 1 id FROM mytable where LOCKGUID is null ORDER BY id;
```

Now update the row with the following SQL, passing in the parameters @MYGUID and @ID

```
Update mytable set LOCKGUID=@MYGUID where LOCKGUID is null and id=@id
```

Now get the record

```
Select id,field1,field2... from mytable where LOCKGUID=@MYGUID and id=@ID
```

If you receive zero results you need to loop from step 1 again as another service claimed this record first.

You could write a stored procedure to do all this processing for you and thus remove the need for multiple round trips to the server.

Comment: I have another question, what if the service has claimed the record and is stopped in between of the processing? Can we process the record which is already claimed but is not completely processed?